# Node.js not installing on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, windows-10

I have tried multiples way to get this off. But it keeps showing me error. Please, is there any way to tackle this? Thanks 
 [The error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be7s0.jpg)

```
This installation package could not be opened. 
Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify 
that this is a valid Windows Installer package.
```

Comment: Looks like a broken download. Have you tried re-downloading the package?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded all possible versions, still getting the same error :(

Comment: Tried running as administrator ?

Comment: Please never post an image of text. Instead edit the question and put the text there.

Comment: I have typed the error

Comment: @gordon_freeman There's not an option to run as Administrator after right clicking.

Comment: Are you an admin ?

Comment: Yes, I'm the administrator.

Comment: I don't download node directly, I use NVM on Mac and NVM for Windows. Maybe if you download node via NVM for Windows, it'll download correctly. https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows. The installer is inside nvm-setup.zip https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

Comment: Can I create a React App with it as well?

Answer (score 3):

Move your downloaded file to different location other than c:/ then it will install.

Comment: This did it for me. It refused to install from C but installed from D.